# How to make VB6 console application which prints output to the command prompt

Tags: vb6, command-prompt, basic, windows-console

I want to make command line VB6 application which prints its result to the command prompt (similar as *printf* in C). However, none of the found solutions does not work for me.

I have VB6 SP6, Windows 7 x64.

I tried 
[How to write to a debug console in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517338/how-to-write-to-a-debug-console-in-vb6)
to accomodate this, but in this line

```
Public SIn As Scripting.TextStream
```

compiler returns an error: **User-defined type not defined**

Why this is not workin? Is there a way to do it?

I would prefer API solution (system independent).

Comment: Tools -> References & tick Microsoft Scripting Runtime or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286924/how-do-i-build-a-vb6-console-app

Comment: Thank you for the second link, this leads to the solution I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is Karl E. Peterson's code at http://vb.mvps.org/samples/Console/ which has complete source, interactive debugging, several examples and many other great features. No need for scripting.

But if you make an EXE file (and sure you would!), it is ***absolutely necessary to fix*** resulting EXE (explanation and manual is on the same Peterson's page), i.e. to set PE bit in EXE header.
Otherwise, if there in EXE is any input waiting, EXE will enter an infinite loop and will never return (but in command-prompt it looks like finished, because prompt is displayed). If you try to start EXE more times, you can see these never-ending processes populating in Task Manager/Processes).